# bash: how can I read text in file into string, modify it and save it another file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file (imaginary):

```
test() {
    echo ${%%NUMBER%%}
}
```

I need:

1. Read it into string variable
2. Replace `%%NUMBER%%` with number
3. Save it to another file, maintaining the multi-line architecture.

How I do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Full path of this script
FILE=`readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`

# This directory path
DIR=`dirname "${FILE}"`

repl() {
    STRING=$(cat $DIR/skel.txt)
    STRING=$(echo $STRING | sed "s/%%NUMBER%%/$1/")
    echo $STRING
 }

# try it
repl 50 > ./out.sh

# tried as well:
# repl 50 | tee ./out.sh
# echo "$(repl 50)" > ./out.sh
# STRING=$(echo -e $STRING | sed "s/%%NUMBER%%/$1/")
```

But I always get everything in one line in `out.sh` file. Need it to stay multiline, as in source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
repl() {
    sed "s/%%NUMBER%%/$1/" "$DIR/skel.txt"
}
```

This is far more efficient, and won't eat your precious newlines.

Comment: Yeah, how would I save it into different file?

Comment: Yeah, this `sed "s/%%NUMBER%%/$1/" "$DIR/skel.txt" | tee ./out.sh` worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov: You can also just do `repl 50 > ./out.sh` as you had before.